# Why Do These GCD, LCM, Modulo, And Mean Graphs Look The Way They Are?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graphing-functions, gcd-and-lcm, means, least-common-multiple

If you couldn't already tell, one of my favorite things about math are the "unconventional" functions, like greatest common divisor, least common multiple, mean, and modulo. For simplicity, I'll refer to these functions as the "strange functions". I know they're not actually called that, but I don't really want to write all four "strange functions" over and over again.
Anyways, a while ago, I made a few graphs in Desmos using almost exclusively the "strange functions", basic arithmetic, and exponents. I used a few logarithms and absolute values, but I used logarithims in a total of 4 functions out of all 44, and absolute value in only 1 function. There was always at least one gcd or lcm in each function. Most of them were written in the style of "functions(x,y) = 1", but a few (especially in the third graph) were written in the style of "functions(x,y) = other_functions(x,y)", and one function in the second graph was written in the style of "|y| = functions(|x|, |1/x|)". Every single graph turned out... odd, to say the least. Could someone please provide an explanation as to why the graphs look this way? Here are the links to the graphs: [Graph 1](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rklooiykfn), [Graph 2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kxzvfoumi3), and [Graph 3](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e0lhni1noj). Here are pictures of the graphs:
Graph 1:[image: Graph 1]Graph 2:[image: Graph 2]Graph 3:[image: Graph 3]
Here is each function individually, the graph of that function, and what is confusing about that graph:
First Graph Functions:
 1. $gcd(x^1,y^1)=1$
 [image: Graph 1 Function 1]
 First things first, why are there squares going away from the origin with a slope of either 1 or negative 1 in each quadrant? Second of all, why are all vertices in the graph at a non-integer multiple of ${1 \over 2}$?
 2. $lcm(x^1,y^1)=1$
[image: Graph 1 Function 2]
Why are there only lines at $\pm {3 \over 4}$?
 3.
 4.
 5.
 6.
 7.
 8.
 9.
 10.
 11.
 12.
 13.
 14.
 15.
 16.
 17.
 18.
Second Graph Functions:
 1. Function 1
 2. Function 2.
 3.
 4.
 5.
 6.
 7.
 8.
 9.
 10.
 11.
 12.
 13.
 14.
 15.
 16.
 17.
 18.
Third Graph Functions:
 1. Function 1
 2. Function 2.
 3.
 4.
 5.
 6.
 7.
 8.

Comment: Oh my god, you have so many tabs open...

Comment: You're sort of asking way too many questions at once.

Comment: Also, the functions $\gcd$ and $\mathrm{lcm}$ aren't defined for *real numbers*, so it's not clear what it even *means* to plot them; who knows what Desmos thinks they should mean. Usually these functions are  only defined for integers, although there is a natural extension to rational numbers.

Comment: I agree with @Hurkyl. Don't rely too much on the graphs for your info... if these functions interest you, do some research into Number Theory.

Comment: I recommend picking one function plot, describing "how" it looks to you, and focus on your difficulty in understanding "why" plot looks that way.  Readers should not be expected to guess what you are thinking.